# Deploy QT WebKitWidgets app to windows XP

Tags: windows, qt, deployment, qtwebkit, qwebkit

Coming from Linux, using QT5.4 (app compiles and works as expected)

If you are interested in the topic, just get fancybrowser example running on a XP machine without QT installed...

My first attempt was using MXE (and manually copying dlls). No success. 
set up VM with Windows XP. 
using **windeployqt**.
app "works" but QWebView doesn't display anything.

trying qt.conf

```
[Paths]
Prefix=.
```

and more things. 
Still **not successful**.

windeployqt with all options to include webkit, compiler, angle...
No success...

Reading about QWebEngine will be the next. 
Compiling a small example on Linux(OK) Windows (Mingw does not support qwebengine!!!). 
So before setting up a new vm with windows 8 (msvc 2010 does not support qwebengine) and may find out the the app won't run on XP....
and porting from QWebView to QWebEngineView....

Please help: 
How to deploy webkitwidgets app on windows? (without installing Qt, which will be my last chance...)

***Edit***

Next step done was Running **ProcessExplorer** on the dev machine and on the target machine. Parsing the output of the loaded dlls on both machines, they do not differ. **All required dlls are loaded**? Still **no display**...

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be solved in Qt5.5.1 which was released last week.
Just use the Deploy Tool of Qt :)